# Convolutional limit equation. How to find which functions it holds for?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, soft-question

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3623776/213607), I started to think about which functions $t\to f(t)$ have the convolutional property ($*$ being convolution) : $$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{(f*h)(t)}{(f*b)(t)} = 2$$

Where $h$ is [Heaviside step-fun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and $b$ is an infinite box-train of some box width $\Delta_t$ multiplied with $h$.

Just for context the mentioned question is an example where a particular choice of partial sum gives us a discrete version of this where $f(t) = t^2\cdot h(t)$ and $\Delta_t = 1$

How to derive which functions this is true for?

Comment: An observation: if the limits of the numerator and denominator are finite, then by the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem), we have
$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{(f*h)(t)}{(f*b)(t)} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{h(t)}{b(t)}$

Comment: I am mostly interested in when they don't.